# Is it possible to have a USB-C male to Ethernet male cable?

Tags: ethernet, usb-c

I use adapters (USB-C male to Ethernet female) and Ethernet cables to have wired network on my USB-C only laptop.

Is there any theoretical issue with having a USB-C male to Ethernet male cable (that has the network card nicely hidden somewhere inside)?

I never saw such a product - closest I saw was some kind of console management cable that couldn't be used for networking [here](https://allegro.pl/oferta/kabel-konsolowy-usb-type-c-rs232-cisco-rj45-1-8m-10089233073?utm_feed=aa34192d-eee2-4419-9a9a-de66b9dfae24&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=_ELKTRK_PLA_Komputery&ev_adgr=Inne&gclid=Cj0KCQjwytOEBhD5ARIsANnRjVjpxvG2_-UdjurSjosG2WpBJwpK2ecFdzFZD36h2EEpc7QBCr5b-OQaAu2nEALw_wcB).

Such cables exist for DisplayPort/HDMI/etc., but they don't seem to exist for Ethernet.

Comment: Management console cable isn’t Ethernet.  Any event what you require is an usb Ethernet device.  You won’t find a cable like the console cable since it’s actually detected as a serial device (which is how you manage network switches)

Comment: Ethernet isn't an alt mode. The functionality / signal does not originate from the USB host / C port like the case in DisplayPort or HDMI (actually HDMI alt mode is less common so sometimes even those cables are active cables that consists of a tiny chip that fits in the plug for signal conversion).

Comment: My question is why didn’t anyone make a cable with a chip that would kill the need for an adapter and be comfortable to use just router -cable- laptop

Comment: Well, I guess it's because WiFi is so common and fast enough these days so no one in the USB-IF or any committee whatsoever bother to get an "Ethernet alt mode" standardized, which will cost the vendors of laptops extra effort / money to build in a NIC and wire it to the complex-enough already USB-C port. (Maybe also the fact that the pins can't matched neatly or so.)

Comment: If you are thinking of a NIC chip in the USB-C plug, well, it's still kind of ugly and inflexible in terms of cable length (like one can carry a dongle and a Ethernet cable of length he/she desires; but if it's what are you thinking of, the length is fixed and the cost per piece is higher, the vendor/retailer will have a headache in stocks and so)

Comment: TL;DR, it's a bad design from a general point of view